# Passing value to AMPscript varible from SSJS is adding hidden chars

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

From some reason, using the following SSJS code:

```
 Platform.Variable.SetValue("@sid", missed[0]["SubscriberKey"]);
```

Adds some hidden characters to the end of the string.
%E2%80%8E is added, which is [Left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark)

It cannot be seen in console.log(), only once I concatenate it to a URL it can be seen in the browser URL input, like this:

http://someaddress?&sid=00Q2o000017qWWyEAM%E2%80%8E

Any idea why?
And how to see these chars in JS or to clean them?

Here a the full code:

```
%%[
var DE_ExternalKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
var EVENT_QR_REGISTERED = DataExtension.Init(DE_ExternalKey);
var missed = EVENT_QR_REGISTERED.Rows.Lookup(['MISSED'],[true],"MISSED_DATE");

Platform.Variable.SetValue("@sid", missed[0]["SubscriberKey"]);
]%%

location.assign'(http://someaddress?&sid='+'%%=v(@mobileNumber)=%%')
```

Comment: Can you add `Write("<br>missed: " + Stringify(missed));` after your `var missed` line and update your question to include the results?

Comment: Also, you aren't appending the value you're setting.  You're setting `@sid` and referencing `@mobileNumber` in the inline AMPscript.

Comment: I feel like there is no reason to really grab this via SSJS and then transfer languages. I would recommend doing it all inside SSJS or all inside of AMPscript as this task is easily done 100% in either language.